Will changing my Macs hard drive name have a bad effect on anything?
My Macs default hard drive name is "Macintosh HD"
I have installed lots of apps and things.
If I change the name from "Macintosh HD" to "Something COOL" will it break my apps or have some other bad effect ?

The Mac article
Rename files, folders, and disks on Mac - Apple Support
says this:

You can change the name of most files, folders, and disks, including the internal hard disk (named Macintosh HD by default). If you change the name of your hard disk, it still appears with its original name on a network.

However, the post
Macintosh HD Accidentally Renamed--Help
does mention some problems, chiefly with the Time Machine:

I just renamed my main HD on accident and now TM doesn't work...even after renaming the main HD back to what it was. Repaired permissions. Nothing...any ideas?

"This backup is too large for the backup disk. The backup requires
575.29 GB but only 515.01 GB are available.
Latest successful backup: Yesterday, 11:30 AM"

Basically after accidentally renaming main HD while cleaning keyboard
and naming it back right after...TM now wants to try and backup the
entire drive instead of continuing with its incremental backups. I've
never had this issue before. It wants to make a complete backup of the
whole drive as it stands....as if it's new.

Basically, any utility that configured itself to work on disks
by name might discover the renamed disk as new, so the old
configuration might need to be removed.
